# How to find IdMappedPortTCP Delphi 7 in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need help. I want to ask about the location of IdMappedPortTCP Delphi 7 in Delphi 2010, because I cannot find it. In delphi 7, I can find it in indy server > tcp port, but how to find it in Delphi 2010?. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Are all packages registered and enabled? Even if a component package is not installed, you still can create instances if you add its source path(s) to the project search path. For Indy, you need `<Indy>Lib\Core`, `Lib\Protocols` and `Lib\System`. (This also makes it easier to switch Indy versions)

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 7 shipped with Indy 8 (or maybe an early Indy 9, I forget which).  Delphi 2010 ships with Indy 10.  A lot of architectural and hierarchical changes between those versions.  On the Component/Tool Pallette, `TIdMappedPortTCP` is located under "Indy Servers".  If you do not have that available then you likely do not have the Indy design-time package loaded in the IDE.